# Is there a way to upgrade Rails in an SVN repo in one step?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svn

Right now, whenever Rails is updated and I upgrade the frozen version in my application (by installing the new gem and refreezing it), in order to commit it into my repository, I need to do two steps: first delete the old version, and second add the new version. This seems to be because when the new version is frozen, the old version (along with the .svn directories) are deleted.

Is there a way to upgrade Rails in my SVN repository in one step? Or alternately, is there a way I can do my next upgrade so that I can more easily upgrade in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from manually (or by script) copying all the .svn directories from the old version to the new (which would be quite a process as each subdirectory has its own .svn directory), there doesn't seem to be a way to do this, because every method of installing (freezing) rails involves removing the existing directory if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

I just finished doing this upgrade.  We moved from Rails 2.0.1 to 2.3.4.  I initially wanted to do this in one step but the .svn directories kept getting in the way.

The simplest solution for me was to create a new branch for my project.  Then I do the two step process (as described above) for each of my gems, plugins and rails where I delete the current version and check in then freeze the new version and check in.  I can then verify it on the branch then merge my two changelists to trunk.